# Xamarin.Forms Binding Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a weird exception where the Compiler tells me that the Specified cast is not valid even though what im doing is very Simple.

I have a ListView binded to a ObservableCollection. And inside my Listview is a ViewCell with a Grid. Xamarin.Forms Version 2.3.2.127

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GiftCollection}">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding GiftName}"/>
          <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding GiftDescription}"/>
          <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding GiftImage}"/>
        </Grid>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Model:

```
 public class GiftModel {

        public string GiftName { get; set; }
        public string GiftDescription { get; set; }
        public ImageSource GiftImage { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class NextRoundViewModel : BaseViewModel {

        public NextRoundViewModel(ApplicationModel applicationModel) {
            ApplicationModel = applicationModel;
            Initialize();
        }

        public ApplicationModel ApplicationModel { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<GiftModel> GiftCollection { get; set; }
        public string CurrentRound => "Runde 2";

        private void Initialize() {
            GiftCollection = new ObservableCollection<GiftModel> {
                new GiftModel {
                    GiftName = "100 Punkte",
                    GiftDescription = "Test",
                    GiftImage = ImageSource.FromFile("Star.png"),
                },
                new GiftModel {
                    GiftName = "200 Punkte",
                    GiftDescription = "Test",
                    GiftImage = ImageSource.FromFile("Star.png"),
                },
                new GiftModel {
                    GiftName = "300 Punkte",
                    GiftDescription = "Test",
                    GiftImage = ImageSource.FromFile("Star.png"),
                },
            };
        }
    }
```

So ive tried everything but if i use for example a TextCell the Exception is gone.
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. It is just weird because i dont know where to look for the Bug.

Comment: which specific binding is causing the problem?  What is the type of the property that is being bound?

Comment: Just the image is Working. The Labels are bound to a simple string. If i replace the Labels with a TextCell the Exception is gone. I need to use the Label :)

Comment: you are binding to CategoryName and Description, are those in your model?

Comment: sorry messed up there. Updated my Answer

Comment: I don't exactly know the reason but its happening when you compile Xaml. To fix that change GiftImage type from ImageSource to string.

Comment: what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: @Kowalski the image is working but even if i remove the image the Exception is the same.

Comment: @Jason i cannot catch the Exception i try catch my entire Code but i cant catch this Exception

Comment: is this a xamarin bug ?

Comment: if it crashes at runtime you should still get a stack trace.

Comment: I was able to copy & paste the code above into a new project, and after deleting references to BaseViewModel and setting the BindingContext, it works just fine. I think the problem is then in code that isn't posted -- some interaction with the surrounding page, BaseViewModel, or how the BaseViewModel is bound to the view. Try simplifying the page on which this ListView is displayed, along with the full page's ViewModel, to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your Time in my baseviewmodel is only Inotifypropertychanged nothing else ive tried your Solution the Problem is still there

Comment: Another step you could try is to define your ViewCell in code instead of XAML, and override OnBindingContextChanged. This will let you put a breakpoint in the debugger and see the BindingContext that is being bound to each cell, and maybe give more insight into what's going wrong. It might also help to post the version of the XAML using TextCell that doesn't crash.

Comment: I tried your code, Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had this problem too, the issue was with the `xaml`. I had a `<StackLayout>` inside of my `<DataTemplate>`, you can remove your `<Grid>` and that should solve the problem.

Did you know that you could replace the `<Grid>` with an `<ImageCell>`:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ImageCell
            Text="{Binding GiftName}"
            Detail="{Binding GiftDescription}"
            ImageSource="{Binding GiftImage}">
        </ImageCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: If you still want to still use Grid wrap it in a ViewCell tag

<ViewCell>
   <Grid>

Answer (score 17):

You can place  inside  with .

Something like this

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
     <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
     </ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `<ViewCell>` from the DataTemplate. This should resolve the error. `<Grid>` will work in `<CollectionView>`

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
         :    
         :    
         </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives the same exception, may help someone:
using ListView or CollectionView but in the ItemTemplate I use **BindableLayout.ItemTemplate** instead **CollectionView.ItemTemplate**

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SummaryInfos}">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

        <!-- this code gives the same exception -->
        <!-- must use CollectionView instead BindableLayout -->
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SomeText}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Do you mean using collectionview.itemTemplate won't get the same exception?