# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on Xamarin.Forms I got error

> "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

I found one similar problem in StackOverflow [Xamarin.Forms Binding Specified cast is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575870/xamarin-forms-binding-specified-cast-is-not-valid)

but here answered as remove grid but in my case, I am not using grid why I am getting error

```
<StackLayout x:Name="roll"  HeightRequest="0"> 

        <SearchBar Placeholder="Type to Search" TextChanged="SearchDropDown" />

        <ListView  x:Name="SearchDropDownList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <input:CheckBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

</StackLayout>
```

I am using `Xamarin.Forms.InputKit` package from **NuGet Package Manager**.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60305/setting-itemssource-for-listview-defined-in-xaml-throws-invalidcastexception-at-runtime

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the error by changing the code into following

```
<ListView  x:Name="SearchDropDownList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>                                   
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <input:CheckBox Text="{Binding Text}" Type="Check"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```